# Log shipping - failed over to secondary, how to fail back

Tags: sql-server-2012, failover, log-shipping, disaster-recovery

SQL 2012

I've been researching and testing Log Shipping as a DR solution. I got the two servers setup. Log shipping is in place and verified to be working correctly. I failed over by restoring the last translog and recovering the database. All this testing was done on VMs on my laptop. At this point everything looks good.

My question now is, how do you fail back? What if this were a true test of the DR in Production. Ok I proved it worked, the test is over, now I need to fail back. Is there a best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this article -- [Reversing Log Shipping](http://sqlmag.com/database-high-availability/3-log-shipping-techniques)! Now what you need to do is to take the log backup with NORECOVERY on the primary and restore this log on the secondary with RECOVERY. This will preserve the log chain.